# select mutate column in data frame created 1 field 2 variable data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

Problem context: data frame has structure as follows. The issue is I need a new column, e.g., status_rank, which is not a data.frame of 2 variables. Then need to update the status_rank with values based on another variable for a conditional.

[typo: ifelse is what I used]

Tried conditional with target.market_b/_g ("Bad", "Good" values). 'status' has these plus more that shall be ignored (not == target.market_b/_g).

```
ifelse(status %in% target.marker_b, "Bad",
       ifelse(status %in% target_g, "Good", "N/A")
```

df$status : chr
df$status_rank : 'data.frame' of 2 variables
.. $status chr "..."
.. $status_rank chr "Bad" "Good" "N/A"

I used a dplyr mutate to create a new field and now I know it mutates the column 'status_rank'. I see now that dplyr mutate is not the correct solution.

```
df$status_rank <- df %>% 
  select(status, status_rank) %>%
     mutate(status_rank = ifelse(status %in% target.marker_b, "Bad",
       ifelse(status %in% target_g, "Good", "N/A")))
```

Issued new column creation with

```
df["status_rank"] <- "N/A"
```

Then mutate operated on 'status_rank' and mutated it into 2 observations. Need a better way to create a new column and apply ifelse(status %in% target.marker_b, "Bad", ifelse(status %in% target_g, "Good", "N/A"). Looking for suggestions.

Data: dput(df$status)

```
"Current", "Fully Paid", "Current", "Fully Paid", "Charged Off", "Current", "Current", "Fully Paid", "Current", "Fully Paid", "Charged Off", "Late (31-120 days)", "Current", "Fully Paid", "Current", "Fully Paid", "Charged Off", "Current", "Current", "Fully Paid", "Late (31-120 days)", "Fully Paid", "Charged Off", "Current"
```

Comment: (1) `elseif` doesn't exist, though you *can* `ifelse(cond1, yes1, ifelse(cond2, yes2, no))`. (2) Sample data would be good, as otherwise we're just stabbing in the dark.

Comment: just added a dput() sample data

Comment: user1857373, you need to remember that we have no data. What you provided gives us enough for that one column (and perhaps for the frame, since no other columns are required), but ... what about your other two variables `target.marker_b` and `target_g`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit difficult to understand what you're talking about without a reproducible example, however the `case_when` function from dplyr may interest you:

```
# Untested code (as no sample data was given)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(status_rank = case_when(
    status %in% target.marker_b ~ "Bad",
    status %in% target_g ~ "Good",
    TRUE ~ "N/A" # Default condition to catch other cases
  ))
```

If you want an `NA` value rather than the character "N/A" then you don't need the default condition. Rows which don't meet any of the conditions will be given the value `NA_character_`.

i.e

```
df %>% 
  mutate(status_rank = case_when(
    status %in% target.marker_b ~ "Bad",
    status %in% target_g ~ "Good"
  ))
```

Comment: "N/A" is what is indicated by the question, so I've gone with both. Thanks for the help @r2evans

Comment: how can I accomplish this without mutate creating 2 variables?

Comment: user1857373, what do you mean? `mutate(status_rank=case_when(...))` is creating precisely one variable.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by creating two variables. `mutate` will only create one variable in this case.

Comment: when I first added, df["status_rank"] <- "N/A", to create the variable. then when I executed the following, mutate created 2 variables [see problem note above]. df$status_rank <- df %>% 
  select(status, status_rank) %>%
     mutate(status_rank = ifelse(status %in% target.marker_b, "Bad",
       ifelse(status %in% target_g, "Good", "NA")))

Comment: two variables: df$status : chr df$status_rank : 'data.frame' of 2 variables .. 1) $status chr "..." .. 2) $status_rank chr "Bad" "Good" "N/A"

Comment: two variables: $status chr, and $status_rank chr

Comment: You need to study up on how to use `dplyr`. The return value from `df %>% select(...) %>% mutate(...)` is a **frame**, not a column, so do not assign it to `df$status_rank`. Just reassign it to `df`.